# How to solve matrix equation in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

The following 8-dimensional matrices are equal,i.e., `matA` is equal to `matB`. How can I solve for the elements `L[i,j,k]` (here `i,j,k` are just labels)?

```
   matA={{1 + L[3, 3, 3], L[3, 3, 1] - I*L[3, 3, 2], L[3, 1, 3] - I*L[3, 2, 3], L[3, 1, 1] - I*L[3, 1, 2] - I*L[3, 2, 1] - L[3, 2, 2], L[1, 3, 3] - I*L[2, 3, 3], 
    L[1, 3, 1] - I*L[1, 3, 2] - I*L[2, 3, 1] - L[2, 3, 2], L[1, 1, 3] - I*L[1, 2, 3] - I*L[2, 1, 3] - L[2, 2, 3], 
    L[1, 1, 1] - I*L[1, 1, 2] - I*L[1, 2, 1] - L[1, 2, 2] - I*L[2, 1, 1] - L[2, 1, 2] - L[2, 2, 1] + I*L[2, 2, 2]}, 
   {L[3, 3, 1] + I*L[3, 3, 2], 1 - L[3, 3, 3], L[3, 1, 1] + I*L[3, 1, 2] - I*L[3, 2, 1] + L[3, 2, 2], -L[3, 1, 3] + I*L[3, 2, 3], 
    L[1, 3, 1] + I*L[1, 3, 2] - I*L[2, 3, 1] + L[2, 3, 2], -L[1, 3, 3] + I*L[2, 3, 3], L[1, 1, 1] + I*L[1, 1, 2] - I*L[1, 2, 1] + L[1, 2, 2] - I*L[2, 1, 1] + 
     L[2, 1, 2] - L[2, 2, 1] - I*L[2, 2, 2], -L[1, 1, 3] + I*L[1, 2, 3] + I*L[2, 1, 3] + L[2, 2, 3]}, 
   {L[3, 1, 3] + I*L[3, 2, 3], L[3, 1, 1] - I*L[3, 1, 2] + I*L[3, 2, 1] + L[3, 2, 2], 1 - L[3, 3, 3], -L[3, 3, 1] + I*L[3, 3, 2], 
    L[1, 1, 3] + I*L[1, 2, 3] - I*L[2, 1, 3] + L[2, 2, 3], L[1, 1, 1] - I*L[1, 1, 2] + I*L[1, 2, 1] + L[1, 2, 2] - I*L[2, 1, 1] - L[2, 1, 2] + L[2, 2, 1] - 
     I*L[2, 2, 2], -L[1, 3, 3] + I*L[2, 3, 3], -L[1, 3, 1] + I*L[1, 3, 2] + I*L[2, 3, 1] + L[2, 3, 2]}, {L[3, 1, 1] + I*L[3, 1, 2] + I*L[3, 2, 1] - L[3, 2, 2], 
    -L[3, 1, 3] - I*L[3, 2, 3], -L[3, 3, 1] - I*L[3, 3, 2], 1 + L[3, 3, 3], L[1, 1, 1] + I*L[1, 1, 2] + I*L[1, 2, 1] - L[1, 2, 2] - I*L[2, 1, 1] + L[2, 1, 2] + 
     L[2, 2, 1] + I*L[2, 2, 2], -L[1, 1, 3] - I*L[1, 2, 3] + I*L[2, 1, 3] - L[2, 2, 3], -L[1, 3, 1] - I*L[1, 3, 2] + I*L[2, 3, 1] - L[2, 3, 2], 
    L[1, 3, 3] - I*L[2, 3, 3]}, {L[1, 3, 3] + I*L[2, 3, 3], L[1, 3, 1] - I*L[1, 3, 2] + I*L[2, 3, 1] + L[2, 3, 2], 
    L[1, 1, 3] - I*L[1, 2, 3] + I*L[2, 1, 3] + L[2, 2, 3], L[1, 1, 1] - I*L[1, 1, 2] - I*L[1, 2, 1] - L[1, 2, 2] + I*L[2, 1, 1] + L[2, 1, 2] + L[2, 2, 1] - 
     I*L[2, 2, 2], 1 - L[3, 3, 3], -L[3, 3, 1] + I*L[3, 3, 2], -L[3, 1, 3] + I*L[3, 2, 3], -L[3, 1, 1] + I*L[3, 1, 2] + I*L[3, 2, 1] + L[3, 2, 2]}, 
   {L[1, 3, 1] + I*L[1, 3, 2] + I*L[2, 3, 1] - L[2, 3, 2], -L[1, 3, 3] - I*L[2, 3, 3], L[1, 1, 1] + I*L[1, 1, 2] - I*L[1, 2, 1] + L[1, 2, 2] + I*L[2, 1, 1] - 
     L[2, 1, 2] + L[2, 2, 1] + I*L[2, 2, 2], -L[1, 1, 3] + I*L[1, 2, 3] - I*L[2, 1, 3] - L[2, 2, 3], -L[3, 3, 1] - I*L[3, 3, 2], 1 + L[3, 3, 3], 
    -L[3, 1, 1] - I*L[3, 1, 2] + I*L[3, 2, 1] - L[3, 2, 2], L[3, 1, 3] - I*L[3, 2, 3]}, {L[1, 1, 3] + I*L[1, 2, 3] + I*L[2, 1, 3] - L[2, 2, 3], 
    L[1, 1, 1] - I*L[1, 1, 2] + I*L[1, 2, 1] + L[1, 2, 2] + I*L[2, 1, 1] + L[2, 1, 2] - L[2, 2, 1] + I*L[2, 2, 2], -L[1, 3, 3] - I*L[2, 3, 3], 
    -L[1, 3, 1] + I*L[1, 3, 2] - I*L[2, 3, 1] - L[2, 3, 2], -L[3, 1, 3] - I*L[3, 2, 3], -L[3, 1, 1] + I*L[3, 1, 2] - I*L[3, 2, 1] - L[3, 2, 2], 1 + L[3, 3, 3], 
    L[3, 3, 1] - I*L[3, 3, 2]}, {L[1, 1, 1] + I*L[1, 1, 2] + I*L[1, 2, 1] - L[1, 2, 2] + I*L[2, 1, 1] - L[2, 1, 2] - L[2, 2, 1] - I*L[2, 2, 2], 
    -L[1, 1, 3] - I*L[1, 2, 3] - I*L[2, 1, 3] + L[2, 2, 3], -L[1, 3, 1] - I*L[1, 3, 2] - I*L[2, 3, 1] + L[2, 3, 2], L[1, 3, 3] + I*L[2, 3, 3], 
    -L[3, 1, 1] - I*L[3, 1, 2] - I*L[3, 2, 1] + L[3, 2, 2], L[3, 1, 3] + I*L[3, 2, 3], L[3, 3, 1] + I*L[3, 3, 2], 1 - L[3, 3, 3]}};
 MatrixForm[matA]



 matB={{\[Alpha]^2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \[Alpha]*\[Beta]}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {\[Alpha]*\[Beta], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \[Beta]^2}};
 MatrixForm[matB]
```

Comment: The wrapper `MatrixForm` is only intended for display, do not include it in the definition of a matrix. To display the matrix when it is being defined, use `MatrixForm[matA = ... ]` so that the wrapper is not included in the definition. `Solve[Thread[matA == matB], var]` evaluates to `{}` which indicates that there is no solution.

Comment: Are you sure this is solvable? You have contradictory conditions on your diagonal ``1 - L[3, 3, 3] = 0`` and ``1 + L[3, 3, 3] = 0``.

Comment: If there were any solutions, then `Solve[matA == matB, Union@ Cases[matA, _L, All] ]` would find them. Try for instance the simpler case: `Solve[{{2,0},{3,-1}}=={{a+b,a-b},{a+c,a-c}},{a,b,c}]`. However, your system of equations has no solutions.

Answer (score 4):

(I edited question's original code in a way that `MatrixForm` is not part of the definitions of `matA` and `matB`. See the comment of @BobHanlon.)

We can use `Thread` and `Solve`.

Here are the variables:

```
vars = Union[Cases[Flatten[matA], L[___], Infinity]]
```

Here we invoke `Solve` over the corresponding system of equations (produces no solutions, see the comment of @Domen):

```
Solve[Thread[Flatten[matA] == Flatten[matB]], vars]

(* {} *)
```

Here is another example using `Reduce` and a subset of the equations:

```
Reduce[Thread[Flatten[matA] == Flatten[matB]][[1 ;; 3]], vars]

(* L[3, 2, 3] == -I L[3, 1, 3] && L[3, 3, 2] == -I L[3, 3, 1] && 
 L[3, 3, 3] == -1 + \[Alpha]^2 *)
```

Comment: When defining the variables it is not necessary to `Flatten` the matrix, i.e., use `vars = Cases[matA, _L, Infinity] // Union;`

Comment: You don't really need to modify the structure of the matrix equations; Solve can ingest the matrices directly. Compare for instance the simpler case: `Solve[{{2,0},{3,-1}}=={{a+b,a-b},{a+c,a-c}},{a,b,c}]`. So here `Solve[matA == matB, Union@ Cases[matA, _L, All] ]` would work, if there were any solutions. (+1)

Comment: @MarcoB Right, that is why I flattened the equations — to show a way to investigate which subsets of them might produce useful solutions.